# Visual studio 2015 smart code completion for referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, codelens

Is there a way, or free extension, or built in functionality of vs15 that can suggest code completion for types that are just referenced but not included with using?
Great example is the way how does the R# works. It suggest type, and later popup question if you want to add using.

I know that when i type full type name and press ctrl + .  it suggest me to import for example Castle.Windsor, but i want it to suggest me type name when i start typing.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior of [quick actions(Ctrl+.)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is by designed, after your type any characters and hover the mouse on it, there is a light bulb appear in the Visual Studio editor and that you can click to perform quick actions including refactoring fixing errors. Light bulbs bring error-fixing and refactoring assistance into a single focal point, often right on the line where you are typing.

If you want it suggests type when you start input character, it is not supported in VS now. I have reported this suggestion to the Visual Studio Product Team in here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17039047-improve-the-prompt-function-of-quick-actions-ctrl, and you can vote it and waiting for the feedback from the VS Product Team engineers and if someone have the same suggestion and they can also vote it.